# DeepLink not opening when containing "https://"

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When  i open deep link, instead  open my app open browser
**Notic**:  when added "https://" on the scheme only open browser

```
 <data
                android:host="games"
                android:pathPrefix="/game"
                android:scheme="https://fahimeZivdar.com" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `android:scheme` attribute should contain **just** a URL scheme.  Also "games" is not a resolvable host name.

Your `<data>` element should probably be:

```
 <data android:host="fahimeZivdar.com"
       android:pathPrefix="/game"
       android:scheme="https" />
```

For more information (including examples), refer to the [Android developer documentation on deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

Comment: I added the "games" like this and the problem was solved  android:pathPrefix="/games/game"